# 公開鍵認証時のエラーについて

Tags: php, ssh, scp

PHPのssh2_auth_pubkey_file関数を使用して公開鍵認証を行いたいのですが、
以下のメッセージが出力され認証できず、困っています。
ここが原因ではないかといったアドバイス等があればよろしくお願い致します。

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
if (!$connection) {
   // 接続失敗
}

$user = 'user';
$pubKey = '/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys';
$priKey = '../id_rsa';

if (!ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $user, $pubKey, $priKey)) {　←★ここでエラー
   // 認証失敗
}
```

> Warning Error: ssh2_auth_pubkey_file(): Authentication failed for user using public key: Unable to open public key file

以下に公開鍵を配置しており、各パーミッションはuserが755、.sshが700、authorized_keysが600です。
/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

※TeraTeamからは公開鍵認証できています。

Comment: そのphpは誰が実行しているのでしょうか？

Comment: $user = exec('whoami');を記載して確認すると、「{PCID}/user」になってました。 apacheではなかったですね。

Answer (score 0):

PHP が Apache 等の web サーバの権限で動作している場合には、ユーザーのホームディレクトリ配下のファイルはアクセス権限の関係で読み取れていない可能性があります。

web サーバの動作ユーザー/グループは環境によって異なりますが、www-data, httpd, apache, nginx 等になります。

公開鍵を上記のユーザーがアクセスできる場所に配置するか、もしくは元のファイルに対して上記ユーザー/グループでアクセスできるように権限を付与する必要があります。

**参考:**
[ssh2_auth_pubkey_file authentication always fails - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23880078/2322778)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
xamppを利用しているのでユーザはapacheになるかと思います。
apacheユーザがアクセスできる場所が分からないため、.ssh、authorized_keysの権限を666にしてみたのですが、同様のエラーとなってしまいました。

Comment: $pubKey が接続先のパスになっていたことが原因でした。認証前に認証後のサーバのディレクトリを参照していました。
ローカルのパスに変更したところ、認証できました。

Answer (score 0):

> $pubKey = '/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys';
> $priKey = '../id_rsa';

ssh2_auth_pubkey_fileの3番目の引数には、公開鍵認証で使用する公開鍵ファイルを指定します。
authorized_keysはサーバー上に置く物であって、通常はクライアント側には無いファイルですよね?
id_rsaを生成した時に対となる公開鍵ファイルid_rsa.pubが生成されているはずなので、(クライアント側に有る)そのファイルを指定してください。
id_rsa.pubが無い場合は、以下のコマンドで秘密鍵ファイルから再生成できます。

```
ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa > id_rsa.pub
```